# Jenkins: Duplicate building of jars in a single build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build

I am using Jenkins 1.596 along with Maven 3.1.1. I have multiple branches in my repository and I am using following goals for build:

```
'-T 5 clean install'
```

When I start the build, it shows following log:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<my_job>/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
....
[workspace] $ /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin/mvn -s /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/settings.xml -T 5 clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

It then shows the projects and Reactor build order. It executes the tests successfully and builds all the jars. Following Success message gets displayed after completion of build:

```
BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:39.752s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 15 00:02:57 BST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 104M/406M
```

Now, the ***issue*** is, just after this success message, it repeats the whole build again. It starts scanning all the poms, downloads jars, executes tests and again, I can see the success message. Following is the starting trace of unwanted build:

```
Parsing POMs
[workspace] $ java -Xmx1024M -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-agent-1.6.jar:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.49.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven31-interceptor-1.6.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.6.jar 54000
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
```

Due to this, the whole build takes twice as much time. I have disabled archiving but that doesn't seem to have affected this. Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to figure out the cause of this. Apparently, the 'Pre Steps' was enabled in jenkins which was doing mvn clean install and then the actual build was configures to start which in turn, was doing the same thing :)
I have removed the pre step and it is now building in half amount of time compared to earlier builds.

Hope this helps someone :)